# Android Designing with LinearLayout , how it works?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am using an Android LinearLayout for a simple page, where I have added 1 ImageView and 1 GridView for both portrait and landscape mode from a single AXML file.

I want in landscape mode all the item comes in one line and in portrait mode gridvew will cut down to the second line.

How can I solve this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">  
  <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView2"
           android:layout_width="300dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"           
           android:src="@drawable/TESTIMAGEGOF"
           android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:columnWidth="75dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:id="@+id/gridView1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting in one layout, you must use java code for this problem, you should do 2 step:

1- you must check orientation in device with java:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){

}
```

2- for set orientation in your LinearLayout try this code:

```
LinearLayout layout = /* ... */;
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

you can use this technique.

Comment: Thank you @Mohammad Akbari for the reply. we are working on Xmarine c# project. so java code will not work. We tried with same code for C# with your reference, but it is not working.                                                                                             
               LinearLayout lin = new LinearLayout(this);
                lin.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

Answer (score 0):

You must create **2** folder in **res** folder with names: **layout**  ,  **layout-land**
and create your **xml** file with same name in this 2 folders, for **layout** use this code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">  
  <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView2"
           android:layout_width="300dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"           
           android:src="@drawable/TESTIMAGEGOF"
           android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:columnWidth="75dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:id="@+id/gridView1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in **layout-land** folder file use this code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">  
  <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView2"
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"           
           android:src="@drawable/TESTIMAGEGOF"
           android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:columnWidth="75dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:id="@+id/gridView1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mohammad Akbari for the reply. I tried this before but the thing is can we do the same in one layout by setting any properties or in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

oh... you work in xamarin.

in xamarin check if orientation is vertical:

```
private double width = 0;
private double height = 0;

protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height); //must be called
    if (this.width != width || this.height != height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        if(width > height){
            //device is landscape
        }
    }
}
```

and for set orientation in LinearLayout use:

```
LinearLayout LLMain = new LinearLayout(this);
LLMain.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
```

Comment: here I have removed orientation from AXML page. but not working.
and the code is

`int LayoutOrientation = WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Orientation;
            if (LayoutOrientation != 0)
            {
                // landscape view                
                
            }
            else
            {
                // Portrait view
                LinearLayout lin = new LinearLayout(this);
                lin.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;                
            }`